# Gedit crashes on opening having upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade, gedit

I upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04

So far its still pretty broken - using gnome flashback things see 'off' and I cannot quite put my finger on the problems. Lots and lots of system crashes and error reports popping up all over the place.

Anyhow apart from those errors which I will need to whittle away I am having a problem with gedit.

When I open it, i get the following error:

> gedit: libz.so.1: no version information available (required by
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2) gedit: relocation error:
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2: symbol gzopen64, version
>   ZLIB_1.2.3.3 not defined in file libz.so.1 with link time reference

Can somebody please help me out here?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get --reinstall install zlib1g libxml2` to reinstall zlib1g & libxml2 libs.

Comment: Same error I am afraid.

Comment: Do you have last update? run `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade`